# How to solve for pyodbc.ProgrammingError: The second parameter to executemany must not be empty

Tags: oracle, python-3.7, pyodbc

Hi i'm having an issue with the transfer of data from one database to another. I created a list using field in a table on a msql db, used that list to query and oracle db table (using the initial list in the where statement to filter results) I then load the query results back into the msql db.

The program runs for the first few iterations but then errors out, with the following error (
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/DataExtracts/BuyerGroup.py", line 67, in 
insertIntoMSDatabase(idString)
File "C:/Users/1/PycharmProjects/DataExtracts/BuyerGroup.py", line 48, in insertIntoMSDatabase
mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: The second parameter to executemany must not be empty.)

I can't seem to find and guidance online to troubleshoot this error message. I feel it may be a simple solution but I just can't get there...

```
# import libraries
import cx_Oracle
import pyodbc
import logging
import time
import re
import math
import numpy as np

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

conn = pyodbc.connect('''Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
                         Server='servername';
                         Database='dbname';
                         Trusted_connection=yes;''')
b = conn.cursor()
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('Hostname', 'port', service_name='name')
conn1 = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'uid', password='pwd', dsn=dsn_tns)
c = conn1.cursor()

beginTime = time.time()

bind = (b.execute('''select distinct field1
                     from [server].[db].[dbo].[table]'''))
print('MSQL table(s) queried, List Generated')

# formats ids for sql string
def surroundWithQuotes(id):
    return "'" + re.sub(",|\s$", "", str(id)) + "'"

def insertIntoMSDatabase(idString):
    osql = '''SELECT distinct field1, field2
                FROM Database.Table
                WHERE field2 is not null and field3 IN ({})'''.format(idString)
    c.execute(osql)
    claimsdata = c.fetchall()
    print('Oracle table(s) queried, Data Pulled')

    mycursor = conn.cursor()
    sql = '''INSERT INTO [dbo].[tablename] 
                (
                 [fields1]
                ,[field2]
                )
            VALUES (?,?)'''

    val = claimsdata
    mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
    conn.commit()

ids = []
formattedIdStrings = []

# adds all the ids found in bind to an iterable array
for row in bind:
    ids.append(row[0])

# splits the ids[] array into multiple arrays < 1000 in length
batchedIds = np.array_split(ids, math.ceil(len(ids) / 1000))

# formats the value inside each batchedId to be a string
for batchedId in batchedIds:
    formattedIdStrings.append(",".join(map(surroundWithQuotes, batchedId)))

# runs insert into MS database for each batch of IDs
for idString in formattedIdStrings:
    insertIntoMSDatabase(idString)

print("MSQL table loaded, Data inserted into destination")

endTime = time.time()

print("Program Time Elapsed: ",endTime-beginTime)

conn.close()
conn1.close()
```

Comment: SQL Server != Oracle

Comment: It looks like you need to test if `val` (a.k.a. `claimsdata`) is an empty list (as would happen if the SELECT returned no rows) and not call `.executemany()` if it is.

Comment: In addition to other suggestions, with cx_Oracle try using bind variables to stop SQL injection security attacks that your string concatenation could be vulnerable to (and binds may also help performance), see [Binding Multiple Values to a SQL WHERE IN Clause](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause).  And tune the data transfers with arraysize and prefetchrows, see [Tuning Fetch Performance](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance).

Comment: i put a test in as @GordThompson suggested and it solved the problem                                        if len(val) < 1 :
        conn.commit()
    else:
        mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
        conn.commit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
>
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: The second parameter to executemany must not be empty.

Before calling `.executemany()` you need to verify that `val` is not an empty list (as would be the case if `.fetchall()` is called on a SELECT statement that returns no rows) , e.g.,

```py
if val:
    mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
```